# where can I find the explanation for logind exit codes?

Tags: systemd, logind

I tried executing the following command, which fails and I get a return code of `-6`. 
I have looked up in the [systemd/logind](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/) documentation, but couldnt find anything helpful in this regard. It only states that upon error it returns a non-zero number.
So I only know `0` means success and anything else is an error.
How am I supposed to know what exactly went wrong so I can fix it?

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 \
/org/freedesktop/login1 'org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.TerminateSession' \
string:c2
```

Comment: It might be errno 6 that is `No such device or address` but you'd have to look in systemd source code.

Comment: And if this is a command you run it means that 6 is returned by `dbus-send`, not systemd.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldnt find any sources that list dbus-send exits codes. Actually I first tried dbus-send, and since I didnt find anything, It occured to me, maybe this is all logind related.